# ExtJS store.loadData() doesn't load the JSON data

Tags: ajax, json, grid, extjs4

I am trying to load a JSON data which is replied back by an AJAX request to a grid.
My store definition:

```
Ext.define('Report.store.CustomerDataStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'Report.model.Customer'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: false,
            storeId: 'CustomerDataStore',
            model: 'Report.model.Customer',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data',
                    record: 'fields'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

There is a button in my app which is defined as follows:

```
xtype: 'button',
handler: function(button, event) {
    var queryform = this.up('form').getForm();
    var me = this;
    if(queryform.isValid())
    {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'customers/',    // where you wanna post
            success: function(response) {
                var mystore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('CustomerDataStore');
                var myData = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                console.log(myData.toSource());
                mystore.loadData(myData);
            },
            jsonData: Ext.JSON.encode(queryform.getValues())
        });
    }
},
```

The problem is that my grid doesn't show the replied data! I am sure that my replied JSON format is OK. I have checked it with a json file. also `myData.toSource()` returns my desired JSON format.
I am pretty confused what I am doing wrong?

Could you plz help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to use loadRawData() function instead of loadData().

Answer (score 3):

`loadData()` loads models i.e. records, and doesn't parse JSON data inside. You need to specify your JSON format in proxy reader and then store will automatically do Ajax call when you call `store.load()`

Comment: But, in this way I have to declare 'url' parameter in my store definition. Am I right? So how to tell the store to load data from Ext.AJAX.request reply?

Comment: You have proxy with type 'ajax' already and url under it empty. Just fill the url and call `store.load()` instead of `Ext.AJAX.request`.